# Detect that a server is running locally by its IP address

Tags: c++, qt, ip-address

My program uses Bonjour to get a list of servers running on various IP addresses on the local network, but one or more of them might be running on the same machine.

I need to know if a server is running on the same machine, by checking its IP address.

For example, servers on `127.0.0.1`, `192.168.0.100`, and `192.168.56.1` are all running on my local machine, but a server on `192.168.0.104` or on `192.168.56.2` would be running on another machine.

Comment: You get a list of all interfaces and their addresses on the local machine. There are many examples on how to do it, both in answers here on SO as well as on the general Internet, so go to your favorite search engine and do a little digging (remember to include your operating system as a search term).

Comment: Why is the question tagged Qt? (=> `QNetworkInterface`)

Comment: @peppe Because my program is written in Qt/C++, and I am using QTcpSocket to connect to those servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QNeworkInterfaces class has a static function that you can call: -

```
QList<QHostAddress> addressList = QNetworkInterfaces::allAddresses();
```

You can then iterate through the addressList and compare those with the server addresses: -

```
bool IsLocalServer()
{
    QList<QHostAddress> addressList = QNetworkInterfaces::allAddresses();

    foreach(QHostAddress address, addressList)
    {
        if(address == QHostAddress("192.168.0.100")
            return true;
        else if(address == QHostAddress("192.168.56.1")
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```